# RegEx and word search doesnt match words with space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, highlight

I have to match Arabic text and highlight them with the current script i can highlight or wrap them in a link for only single words, How to modify this script so that it can match multiple words also.

```
text = text.replace(
    /([\u0600-\u06ff]+)([^\u0600-\u06ff]+)?/g,
replacer);
```

Complete Code

```
(function () {
    // Our keywords. There are lots of ways you can produce
    // this map, here I've just done it literally
    //الولايات المتحدة الأمريكية, الولايات المتحدة, اوباما, وأمريكا, والتفاوض, وإيران, الاتفاق النووي, الخليج العربي, الخليج الفارسي

    var keywords = {
        "الخليج العربي": true,
            "الاتفاق النووي": true,
            "الخليج العربي": true,
            "وإيران": true,
            "والتفاوض": true,
            "وأمريكا": true,
            "اوباما": true,
            "الولايات المتحدة": true,
            "الولايات المتحدة الأمريكية": true
    };

    // Loop through all our paragraphs (okay, so we only have two)
    $("p").each(function () {
        var $this, text;

        // We'll use jQuery on `this` more than once,
        // so grab the wrapper
        $this = $(this);

        // Get the text of the paragraph
        // Note that this strips off HTML tags, a
        // real-world solution might need to loop
        // through the text nodes rather than act
        // on the full text all at once
        text = $this.text();

        // Do the replacements
        // These character classes just use the primary
        // Arabic range of U+0600 to U+06FF, you may
        // need to add others.
        text = text.replace(
            /([\u0600-\u06ff]+)([^\u0600-\u06ff]+)?/g,
        replacer);

        // Update the paragraph
        $this.html(text);
    });

    // Our replacer. We define it separately rather than
    // inline because we use it more than once      
    function replacer(m, c0, c1) {
        // Is the word in our keywords map?
        if (keywords[c0]) {
            // Yes, wrap it
            c0 = '<a class="red" href="#">' + c0 + '</a>';
        }
        return c0 + c1;
    }
})();
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/u3k01bfw/1/

actual source [Text Matching not working for Arabic issue may be due to regex for arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664267/text-matching-not-working-for-arabic-issue-may-be-due-to-regex-for-arabic)

i simply want to match the keywords and wrap them around HTML which can be `<span></span>` or `<a href="#"> <a/>` for highlight the matched keywords or converting them in links

**Update**: I had also used other plugins like [Highlight](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) but that also breaks for arabic, As one of the users had recommended the Highlight plugin as a solution but it breaks as mentioned in this question raised last week https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533793/highlighting-of-text-breaks-when-for-either-english-or-arabic.

I also have other issue with the approach which i have take,

1. It works properly if Arabic words are wrapped in `"` or separated by `,` or and sometime last word doesn't match if i remove `\s` from the regex
2. There may be other condition where it may breaks so far i have tried to fix one issue but then other thing breaks.

I would appreciate help in this regard, I simply want to match exact Arabic keywords using any plugin which works properly, so far i have tried few option but they have one of the other issues

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach isn't the regex. You match each **word** individually, and then check if that word is a keyword. If `keywords` contains something that *isn't a word* you will never match it.

One option is to change the regex pattern to be based on your `keywords`.

For example:

```
var keywords = [ "الخليج العربي","الاتفاق النووي","الخليج العربي",
                 "وإيران","والتفاوض","وأمريكا","اوباما",
                 "الولايات المتحدة الأمريكية","الولايات المتحدة"];
var keywordRegexp = new RegExp(keywords.join("|"), 'g');
```

and then:

```
text = text.replace(keywordRegexp, '<a class="red" href="#">$&</a>');
```

or:

```
function replacer(g0) {
    return '<a class="red" href="#">' + g0 + '</a>';
}
text = text.replace(keywordRegexp, replacer);
```

Some notes on that:

- I've changed `keywords` to an array for convenience.
- If your `keywords` may contain RegExp metacharacter, you may want to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/7586) them. Maybe not.
- You may need to reorder `keywords` so that longer words come first. Specifically, `"hello world"` should be before "hello".

Working example: **http://jsfiddle.net/u3k01bfw/5/**

---

I would also mention the [jQuery Highlight Plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html), which makes short work of this problem:

```
$("p").highlight(keywords);
```

Working example: **http://jsfiddle.net/u3k01bfw/6/**

Comment: I tried Highlight plugin also problem with it was that it matched any combination, I had also posted question regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533793/highlighting-of-text-breaks-when-for-either-english-or-arabic.

Comment: If i add keywords with `</br>` then it breaks http://jsfiddle.net/u3k01bfw/7/ and usually it doesn't match the last word

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker - Can you please edit the question to include all of these cases?